# Running a shell command in a c program

Tags: c, linux, shell

I want to run a shell command in my c program. But the thing is that i don't want to make my program wait until the command performed. No need to read the shell command's output (it returns no data anyway)  So basically, is that possible?

Comment: BTW, it does not matter if you want to run a shell command or some other executable. Whether you use `system()` or the `fork()/exec()` approach, all that's required is an executable. Maybe you want to edit the title of your question accordingly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fork()` and `system()` is what you need

Comment: Along with exec() or its variants, probably.

Comment: `system` would have the child process wait for the shell command - `exec` would replace the child process with the shell..

Comment: @Ronald: no. It replaces the child process with another process. It's not clear from the OP if he wants to run another program or a shell command line, but if it's the latter, then only system() will do the trick. exec does not involve the shell.

Comment: it will if you pass it the proper arguments (i.e. start /bin/sh and pass it the script you want to run).

Answer (score 6):

Sure, just `fork` and `exec`: use `fork` to create a new process and, in the child process, use `exec` to start the shell with your command. `execv` takes the arguments you would normally give to the shell.

Your code could look like this:

```
pid_t child_pid = fork();
if (child_pid == 0)
{   // in child
    /* set up arguments */
    // launch here
    execv("/bin/sh", args);
    // if you ever get here, there's been an error - handle it
}
else if (child_pid < 0)
{   // handle error
}
```

the child process will send a `SIGCHLD` signal when it dies. This code quoted from the POSIX standard (SUSv4) will handle that:

```
static void
handle_sigchld(int signum, siginfo_t *sinfo, void *unused)
{
    int status;

    /*
     * Obtain status information for the child which
     * caused the SIGCHLD signal and write its exit code
     * to stdout.
    */
    if (sinfo->si_code != CLD_EXITED)
    {
        static char msg[] = "wrong si_code\n";
        write(2, msg, sizeof msg - 1);
    }
    else if (waitpid(sinfo->si_pid, &status, 0) == -1)
    {
        static char msg[] = "waitpid() failed\n";
        write(2, msg, sizeof msg - 1);
    }
    else if (!WIFEXITED(status))
    {
        static char msg[] = "WIFEXITED was false\n";
        write(2, msg, sizeof msg - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        int code = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        char buf[2];
        buf[0] = '0' + code;
        buf[1] = '\n';
        write(1, buf, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: exec does not involve the shell. suppose the OP wants to run `ls | grep -v hello`. This will work with system, but will not work with exec.

Comment: the OP can pass those to the shell - system does the same thing (but does another `fork` & `exec` behind the scenes).

Answer (score 2):

What about simply amping the command with `system ("command &")`?

Answer (score 1):

Try code like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
     if (!fork())
     {
         execv("ls", {"myDir"}); /* Your command with arguments instead of ls. */
     }
}
```

Comment: This strikes me as too quick and dirty as this would create a zombie process from the time the command exits until main exits. A well-behaved Unix program would want to avoid that. See other answers that use `waitpid`.