# Running shell script from C

Tags: c, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running a shell command in a c program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609074/running-a-shell-command-in-a-c-program)

I am running a shell script from C.It is executed using system().How to pass parameters to this script?

Comment: just pass them in the string you hand out to `system`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Note that using system() is a Bad Idea in many ways, see here for why http://www.webinmind.net/bpc.html#six

Comment: He wants to run a shell **script** from C, not a shell **command**. Big difference, and therefore **not a duplicate**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`system` takes a single string containing the entire command line, so you'd pass

```
system("/your/shell/script 'argument 1' 'argument 2'");
```

It is rarely a good idea to use `system`, because you'll have to escape all meta-characters yourself – even spaces are a problem, as you can see above. You're looking for one of the exec* functions, for example execv. Its first argument is the name of the program (in your case `/bin/sh` or the shell script itself), its second is a NULL-terminated list of argument strings:

```
char* program = "/your/shell/script";
char* args[3];
args[0] = "argument 1";
args[1] = "argument 2";
args[2] = NULL;
execv(program, args);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
system("scriptname arg1 arg2")
```

Comment: i did that earlier but echo $1 and echo $2 doesnt print anything

Comment: you might be passing string as argument. you have to use 'arg' if you are using string.