# How to call unix commands from C program

Tags: c, unix, echo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running a shell command in a c program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609074/running-a-shell-command-in-a-c-program)

I want to call echo in a C program and then redirect its output to a file. But I am not sure how to call unix commands in C program. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Aashish

Comment: Why are you calling `echo`?? What about the `*printf` functions? (E.g. `FILE * f = fopen("file", "w"); fprintf(f, "words"); fclose(f);`)

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("echo test > filename");
    return 0;
}
```

is the trivial way to do this. If you want more control over the process then you should investigate [fork/exec](http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~franco/OpSys-304-427/lecture-notes/node16.html).

However you can write files trivially using the C stdlib file functions. That would be *much more* lightweight than spawning a new process.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to using `system` to execute a UNIX command in C is [execlp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp).

It all depends on the way you want to use them. If you want user input, then you might want to use execlp / [execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve). Otherwise, `system` is a fast, easy way to get UNIX working with your C program.

For redirection, you can use [pipes](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe).
It will help you look at data you want to redirect to a file you opened. With `system` you just set it but have no real options to set it or optimise it the way you would like.

Answer (score 3):

If you specifically want to execute this program in order to grab its output, you rather want [popen()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/popen.html) instead of system().

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [system](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/system.html) function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  system("echo 'words' > file");
  return 0;
}
```

or using fopen, printf, fclose.